# In MySQL how to check if a number is between a range of numbers from a series of ranges

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if we have a MySQL query to check if a number exist between a range of numbers.

I have two tables

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 192056 |
| 2 | 143067 |

| ID | start Range | end Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 192000 | 192100 |
| 1 | 182000 | 182100 |
| 2 | 163000 | 163100 |
| 2 | 152000 | 152100 |

I need to join these two table on column ID and check if number from 1st table is between the range from the 2nd table.

Output:

192056 - true

143067 - false

Thank you!

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with?  It would help to see what you have tried or how far you got, and what your desired results look like

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `LEFT JOIN` and put the `ON` condition with `>=` and `<=` operator. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
ID INT,
Numbers INT);

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES
(1,192056),
(2,143067);

CREATE TABLE tableB (
ID INT,
start_Range INT,
end_Range INT);

INSERT INTO tableB VALUES
(1,192000,192100),
(1,182000,182100),
(2,163000,163100),
(2,152000,152100);

SELECT * FROM 
  tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b 
ON a.Numbers >= b.start_Range 
AND a.Numbers <= b.end_Range;
```

As for the indication, you may define it using `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT a.Numbers, 
       CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS 'Checking' 
FROM 
  tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b 
ON a.Numbers >= b.start_Range 
AND a.Numbers <= b.end_Range
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f272b24f73c1dbc9d1f6307435480c63)

Comment: This does help. Thank you so much